# Trying to print a hash table but i keep getting the memory location

Tags: java, hashtable

Hey I keep trying to print my hash table but even when I use my toArray and toString methods all it prints is the memory location. I'm really confused because I thought toArrays and toStrings were for this very problem. Any help would be appreciated.

I declare my hash table like this:

```
 HashTable<Integer,EmployeeInfo> phone =  new HashTable<>(300);
```

Again, when I try to do these all I get is the memory location and not the actual data that the hash table holds. For example when I do phone.toString() all I get is: hashing.HashTable@55f96302. Any help would be appreciated, thanks :).

```
package hashing;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Hash {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     HashTable<Integer,EmployeeInfo> phone =  new HashTable<>(300);
     System.out.println(phone.toString());
}

public static class HashTable<K,V>
{
    private int numberEntries;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 5;

    private HashHolder<K,V>[] hashTable;
    private int tableSize;

    public HashTable()
    {
        this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
    }


    public HashHolder<K,V>[] toArray()
    {
        int size = hashTable.length;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashHolder<K,V>[] tempArray = Arrays.copyOf(hashTable,size);//(HashHolder<K,V>[]) new Object[size];
        return tempArray;
    }
    public HashTable(int initCapacity)
    {   
        //Note: I'm not implementing a rigorous check for capacity constraints here.  I probably should...
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashHolder<K,V>[] temp = (HashHolder<K,V>[]) new HashHolder[initCapacity];
        hashTable = temp;

        numberEntries = 0;
    }



}

public static class HashHolder<K,V> 
{
    private K hashKey;
    private V data;
    private HashHolder<K,V> next;
    private States state;
    private enum States {CURRENT,REMOVED};


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        if(state != States.REMOVED)
            return String.format("%s: %s", hashKey.toString(), data.toString());
        else
            return String.format("REMOVED");
    }
    public HashHolder(K key, V value)
    {
        hashKey = key;
        data = value;
        state = States.CURRENT;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: have you overridden the the `toString()` method in `EmployeeInfo.java`

Comment: did you miss `@Override` annotation..?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] which anyone can compile and run themselves. You should include enough code to illustrate what you are asking about, but no more. Be sure that the code you post compiles without any errors.

Comment: "when I do phone.toString() all I get is: hashing.HashTable@55f96302" This is because `HashTable` does not override `toString()`. You must iterate over the elements manually.

Comment: @BagusTesa I have an override but it did not change anything.

Comment: Note that `HashTable` is deprecated since Java 2 (that was over 15 years ago). `HashMap` is the preferred data structure to use instead.

Comment: well, as we see.. `hashing.HashTable@55f96302` will be shown if you call a `HashTable` instance's `toString()` method. Now, i am wondering whether your `toString()` is implemented in a class that extend `HashTable` or... what..? also, what is your JDK version?

Comment: Are you using `Hashtable` from the Java API or are you in a data structures class where you are writing your own `HashTable` class?

Comment: @BagusTesa My `toString()` is in a class called `HashHolder<K,V>` where k is key and v is value. EmployeeInfo does not extend `HashTable` or `HashHolder<K,V>`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm using my own `HashTable` class

Comment: You should post the parts of the class that are relevant to this question, including the class declaration itself: `class HashTable { /* blah blah */ }`. The code you have posted will not compile because it is not inside a class. Please read the link I gave previously for more suggestions about posting code.

Comment: @BagusTesa I'm using Java 8 update 131

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I tried to add the code as you requested, if need be I can post the entirety of both classes

Comment: You do not need to post all of your code. You only need to show enough code so that anyone can understand your question. Also, we should be able to copy and paste it and compile it without any additional errors. You have a good start. However, both `HashTable` `HashHolder` are missing a closing braces and have no methods. Which of the methods from the original post are supposed to be inside `HashTable`? Which are supposed to be in `HashHolder`? Move them here they belong.

Comment: You posted a `toString` method. What class is it for? Your `HashTable` class needs a `toString` method so that when you try to print it, you get a string that shows maybe what it contains, or a descriptive name.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice there ya go. I hope that helps, sorry for the hassle lol I don't use this site much

Comment: Now you need to add a `main()` method in order for anyone to run your program. `main()` can be in its own class or in one of the existing classes. Also be sure that the code you post here compiles without any errors. You should create a new directory with .java files that have the exact code which you post here. That way you can test it for any compiler errors. This will save a lot of time for both of us.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Got it

Comment: This program has no output since `main()` does nothing. Please fix this so that your program will show the exact output you are asking about.

Comment: hi @themaster389, looks like.. you had `toString()` method for `HashHolder`, but did not specify one for `HashTable`, why is it? if you call a `HashTable` instance's `toString()` it'll end up in `object`'s implementation for `toString()`..

Comment: @Code-Apprentice main should run now and print the memory location

Comment: You need to override `toString()` in `HashTable` in order to get any meaningful output. (p.s. The current version of code has a compiler error because `HashTable` has no constructor which takes an argument. The best way to fix this for this question is to remove the no-args constructor, relying on the default constructor, and pass no arguments when you create a `HashTable` with `new`.)

Comment: It's not a "memory address" that you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Your `HashTable` class needs its own `toString()` method that produces some reasonable output.  Otherwise, you just get the default `toString` behavior from `Object` that prints the more-or-less useless `hashing.HashTable@55f96302` you are seeing.